# Python: finding all classes with a particular attribute

Tags: python, attributes

I saw a nearly identical post for C#, but couldn't find anything relevant for Python.

Because I'm just starting to learn Python, I have a feeling I'll think of an attribute I've used before like .count() and forget which objects have the attribute.

I want to write a function that, given the directory list and a certain attribute, will return a set of the object classes that have the attribute. (Ideally I could search all classes objects imported at the time of the running of this function, not just what's in dir())

Here is what I have so far:

```
    def whereattr(directory_list, attrib):
        haveit = set()
        for obj in directory_list:
            try:
                haveit.add(type(eval(obj)) if hasattr(eval(obj), attrib) else '')
            except:
                pass
        return haveit
```

I am using try/except because I found I'm unable to evaluate all objects.

Example:

```
    In [244]: whos
    Variable       Type         Data/Info
    -------------------------------------
    DataFrame      type         <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    Series         type         <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
    count          int          5
    counts         dict         n=97
    first_letter   function     <function <lambda> at 0x1039daf50>
    frame          DataFrame          _heartbeat_        <...>n[3560 rows x 18 columns]
    get_counts     function     <function get_counts at 0x10770ac08>
    haveit         list         n=0
    itertools      module       <module 'itertools' from <...>ib-dynload/itertools.so'>
    json           module       <module 'json' from '/Use<...>on2.7/json/__init__.pyc'>
    letter         str          A
    line           str          { "a": "Mozilla\/4.0 (com<...>.935799, -77.162102 ] }\n
    names          _grouper     <itertools._grouper object at 0x103b51b90>
    path           str          pydata-book/ch02/usagov_b<...>2012-03-16-1331923249.txt
    rec            dict         n=16
    records        list         n=3560
    results        Series       0                Mozilla/<...>ngth: 3440, dtype: object
    test           set          set([])
    testfun        function     <function testfun at 0x107b2d938>
    tz             unicode      Asia/Seoul
    tzs            list         n=3440
    vkp            list         n=97
    whereattr      function     <function whereattr at 0x107b2d9b0>
    x              unicode      Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; <...>T4.0E; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)

    In [247]: whereattr(dir(), "count")
    Out[247]: {'', str}
```

Would someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Clearly, list, Series, etc. have a count attribute and should be included.

In addition, if you want to scold me for any other problems with my code, I'm open to (nice) criticism.

Comment: What exception do you get if you take out the `try`-`except`?

Comment: Removing the try-except:
...
'NameError: name 'DataFrame' is not defined'

Comment: There is something strange going on in this example.  If a variable name appears in `dir()` in the global scope, it should not cause a `NameError` in `eval()`.  Is the code in your question exactly what you executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dir` is a bit useless here, I would rather recommend `locals` or `globals` as that gives you the references so you won't need to use eval.

```
[label for label, ref in locals().items() if hasattr(ref, 'count')]
```

Obviously you could put that into a function like

```
whereattr = lambda scope, attr: [label for label, ref in scope.items() if hasattr(ref, attr)]
```

and you use it like this

```
whereattr(locals(), 'count')
```

or

```
whereattr(vars(__builtin__), 'count')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `eval()` to look up the objects.  Try something like this instead:

```
def whereattr(directory_list, attrib):
    haveit = set()
    scope = globals()
    for obj_name in directory_list:
        if obj_name in scope:
            obj = scope[obj_name]
            if hasattr(obj, attrib):
                haveit.add(type(obj))
    return haveit
```

This will find all objects in the global scope having the given attribute.

**Edit:** Even though using `eval()` is bad practice, your original code should have worked.  So I'm actually not sure what the underlying problem is.  (See my comment on the original question.)

Comment: Hmm, when I use your code, it just returns set(), like as if haveit never gets altered. Did this code work for you?

Comment: @user3131893 This will only work for objects in the "global" (module) scope.  Objects that are not defined in this scope will be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your except clause to `except Exception, e: print str(e)`. It's telling you what you are doing wrong. If you lose the `eval`, it seems to work.

```
def whereattr(directory_list, attrib):
        haveit = set()
        for obj in directory_list:
            try:
                haveit.add(type(obj) if hasattr(obj, attrib) else '')
            except Exception, e:
                print str(e)
        return haveit 

>>> whereattr([list], "count")
set([<type 'type'>])
>>>
```

Comment: The "objects" in directory_list are string variable names.  The OP wants to look up these names in the scope, which is why he was using `eval()`.

Comment: yeah, your way is better for sure. Just wanted to point out the eval error